# Update textview inside a function

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, textview

I'm new here and this is my first post!
I try to learn Android app development and I'm stuck with this problem :

How can I update a textview inside a function? I code a small app which generates all the permutation with repetitions and write it in a textview.

It works, but the textview updates only at the end of all the permutations... Don't understand why...

Sorry if my English is bad, I'm French ;)

I try to use Thread, the app doesn't crash, it seems to work but the app goes directly in the background...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        permutation2("abcdefgh", 8)
    }

    private fun permutation1(text: String, prefix: String, n: Int, k: Int): String {

        if (k == 0) {
        } else
            for (i in 0..n) {
                val newprefix = prefix + text[i]
                if (newprefix.length >= text.length) {
                    zoneTexte.text = newprefix
                }
                permutation1(text, newprefix, n, k - 1)
            }
        return "Erreur"
    }

    private fun permutation2(text: String, k: Int) {
        permutation1(text, "", text.length - 1, k)
    }
}
```

Functions for permutations work well but the textview update only at the end (with the last permutation "hhhhhhhh") and I would like to update it for each permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        permutation2("abcdefgh", 8)
    }


    private fun permutation2(text: String, k: Int) {
        MyCal().execute(text)
    }

    inner class MyCal : AsyncTask<String ,String, String>(){
        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
            zoneTexte.text = values[0]

        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            zoneTexte.text = result
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
            return permutation1(p0[0]!!, "", p0[0]!!.length?.minus(1), 8)
        }

        fun permutation1(text: String, prefix: String, n: Int, k: Int): String {
            if (k == 0) {
            } else
                for (i in 0..n) {
                    val newprefix = prefix + text[i]
                    if (newprefix.length >= text.length) {
                        onProgressUpdate(newprefix)
                        return newprefix
                    }
                    permutation1(text, newprefix, n, k - 1)
                }
            return "Erreur"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kishan ! But when I try your code the app open and close directly without crash... But maybe your code will help me ! I will try to analyze it !

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.testpermutation, PID: 27087
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Comment: Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 1):

onCreate is executed on the ui-thread, as is the case for permutation1() and permutation2().  The ui won't actually refresh until onCreate completes and ui can then refresh/redraw the screen, so that's why you don't see any incremental text updates until the end.

If you would like to see it update in real time, you may want to look into [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).  In your particular example, you aren't really performing a long running task, so I'm not sure if you'll be able to see the incremental additions to your TextView even if you use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

After the help from Mark and Kishan I find the solution ! Thank you guys !

Here is the code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    permutation2("abcdefgh", 8)

}


private fun permutation2(text: String, k: Int) {
    MyCal().execute(text)
}

inner class MyCal : AsyncTask<String ,String, String>(){
    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
        runOnUiThread(Runnable { zoneTexte.text = values[0] })

    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        runOnUiThread(Runnable { zoneTexte.text = result })
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
        return permutation1(p0[0]!!, "", p0[0]!!.length?.minus(1), 8)
    }

    fun permutation1(text: String, prefix: String, n: Int, k: Int): String {
        if (k == 0) {
        } else
            for (i in 0..n) {
                val newprefix = prefix + text[i]
                if (newprefix.length >= text.length) {
                    onProgressUpdate(newprefix)
                    return newprefix
                }
                permutation1(text, newprefix, n, k - 1)
            }
        return "Erreur"
    }
}
```

}